# How to validate City Name using RegExp in PL/SQL

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Am using Oracle 11g as my database and PL/SQL as the SQL language to validate certain columns inside a table.

Requirement(s):

1. Validate a "City Name" so that it only contains alpha characters and no numbers.
2. Can contain a space for cities such as San Jose or San Francisco.

   ```
   function ValidateCity(city in varchar2) return varchar2 is
       valid varchar2(50) := 'valid';
   begin
       if not REGEXP_LIKE (city, '^[A-Z\s]*$') then
          valid := (case when valid = 'valid' then '' else valid end) 
                    || 'Does not match pattern ^[A-Z\s]*$ ';
       else
          valid := 'Required ';
       end if;
      return valid;
   end;
   ```

This works when I pass in a single city name like "Tucson" but not when there is a space, e.g. San Francisco or Los Angeles.

Any hints / suggestions / advice is welcome!

Thank you for taking the time for reading this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`normal* (special normal*)*` again...

`^[[:alpha:]]+([-[:space:]][[:alpha:]]+)*$`

Oracle regexes do not support `\s`, see [here](http://psoug.org/reference/regexp.html). `[:alpha:]` and `[:space:]` are POSIX character classes and always need to be in character classes. `[-[:space:]]` means "a dash, or a space character". You may wish to replace `[:space:]` with a single space character instead.

[edited to simplify: `special` here is really only either a dash or a space]

Comment: [:space:] is the POSIX character class.  It includes space, newline, vertical tab, horizontal tab.  Did you mean to accept those as part of city name?  And yes I know it might be difficult to get a tab character entered, but it would wreak havoc on some kinds of queries.

Comment: I was wondering about this too, but the original example had `\s` which does include all of these in certain dialects :p

Comment: fge: Thank you so much! Yes, now it works with cities that have spaces in between their names such as 'San Francisco' and / or 'Los Angeles', however, I also need it to work with cities that have dashes inside them such as 'KAILUA-KONA'. Tried using ^[A-Z]+([[-]][A-Z]+)*$ but it didn't work. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Will this regex expression support both spaces and dashes? Will it allow Kailua-Kona and San Francisco? Thanks so much fge!

Comment: Be aware some cities have more than one space; specifically San Luis Obispo, CA.

Comment: @AdamMusch my regex takes that into account, if you read it. It is the `(special normal*)*` part.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, Oracle does support Perl style regular expressions: [Perl-Influenced Extensions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm#CHDDGICJ)